# make tab bar with custom design in flutter

Tags: flutter

Now I want to create custom Tab Bar. I want two diffrent tab bar according to the picture. Anyone can help?

[image: click to view the picture]

Comment: This is an exact copy of another question in here, with the exact same design. Avoid spam, please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68783122/how-to-custom-tab-bar-in-flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For two Tap**

```
class BottomNavBAr extends StatelessWidget {
  final int selectedItem;

  final Function callbackFromNav;

  const BottomNavBAr({
    Key? key,
    required this.callbackFromNav,
    required this.selectedItem,
  }) : super(key: key);

  get _radius => Radius.circular(8);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => SizedBox(
        height: kToolbarHeight,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                width: constraints.maxWidth * .85,
                height: kToolbarHeight * .7,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.deepPurple.shade900,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: constraints.maxWidth * .88,
                child: LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (context, constraints) => Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      ChipItem(
                        text: "Deposit",
                        width: constraints.maxWidth * .5,
                        isSelected: 0 == selectedItem,
                        oncallBack: () => callbackFromNav(0),
                        decoration: 0 == selectedItem
                            ? BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.amberAccent,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: _radius,
                                  topRight: _radius,
                                  bottomLeft: _radius,
                                ),
                              )
                            : BoxDecoration(),
                      ),
                      ChipItem(
                        text: "WithDrawal",
                        width: constraints.maxWidth * .5,
                        isSelected: 1 == selectedItem,
                        decoration: 1 == selectedItem
                            ? BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.amberAccent,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: _radius,
                                  topRight: _radius,
                                  bottomRight: _radius,
                                ),
                              )
                            : BoxDecoration(),
                        oncallBack: () => callbackFromNav(1),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChipItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;

  final String text;
  final bool isSelected;
  final Function oncallBack;

  final BoxDecoration decoration;

  const ChipItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.oncallBack,
    required this.text,
    required this.width,
    required this.isSelected,
    this.decoration = const BoxDecoration(),
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => oncallBack(),
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        width: width,
        decoration: decoration,
        child: Text(
          text,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: isSelected ? 24 : 16,
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: isSelected ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Use like**

```
  int selectedItem = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: BottomNavBAr(
        selectedItem: selectedItem,
        callbackFromNav: (v) {
          setState(() {
            selectedItem = v;
          });
        },
      )),
    );
  }
```